# Is it possible to fire a JavaScript function on a SharePoint Control in Application pages?

Tags: 2010, javascript, application-pages, field-controls, codebehind

I am working on SharePoint Application pages. I have a SharePoint DropDownChoiceField control on the aspx page. The requirement is to auto populate this control at the time of page load.

1. Is there a way to call a JavaScript function at any of the events say "onload"?
2. I am also unable to find this control on the code behind page.

   SharePoint:DropDownChoiceField FieldName="DropDownOptions" ID="ListValue" runat="server">

Thanks

Comment: Why are you not using ASP.NET Drop down list control instead? You can use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");` to make your JavaScript function run on load.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri: Thanks a lot for the help. Could you please write it as answer so that i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using ASP.NET Drop down list control instead?

You can use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myCustomFunctionName");` to make your JavaScript function run on load.

Answer (score 1):

You can call javascript from code behind as:

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);

where MyFunction() is your javascript function

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/443131/Call-to-javascript-Function-from-code-behind-using